# ios:how to Convert html data to nsstring?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi friends in my project am datas from `JSONserialization`. where a certain data is received as `html data` like this 
`<p>activity for m43 by c31</p>` 
i need to convert this data to `nsstring` and have display it . i dont know how to convert it please help me thanks in advance. i have gone through some solution but am not clear.How do I convert HTML NSData to an NSString? please help me thanks in advance

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
 tweet = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
    tweet = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
        [array1 addObject:[item objectForKey:@"activityTitle"]];//prints string data
        [array2 addObject:[item objectForKey:@"activityType"]];//prints string data
        [array3 addObject:[item objectForKey:@"id"]];//prints string data
        [array4 addObject:[item objectForKey:@"sessionId"]];//prints string data
 [array8 addObject:[item objectForKey:@"desc"]];// prints html data
 NSLog(@"%@",array2);
       NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:webData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"hiiiiiii",str);
}
```

i dont know how to convert that array8(containing html data) to nsstring. i need to display it uitableviewcell. like this
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier =@"activismCell";
    CAviewCELLCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

```
cell.activitytitle.text = (NSString *)[array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.idline.text = (NSString *)[array3 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.descline.text = (NSString *)[array8 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.issuelabel.text = (NSString *)[array9 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.timelabel.text = (NSString *)[array10 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

sessid = (NSString *)[array4 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
token = (NSString *)[array6 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
apikey = (NSString *)[array7 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"%@,%@",sessid,token);
NSString *stat =(NSString *)[array2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"%@",stat);
NSString *trimmedString = [stat stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
if([trimmedString isEqualToString:@"Two Way Video Streaming"] || [trimmedString isEqualToString:@"One Way Video Streaming"]) {
    [cell.startvideo setHidden:FALSE];
    [cell.startvideo setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ca_video.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.startvideo addTarget:self action:@selector(playAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
else
    [cell.startvideo setHidden:TRUE];
return  cell;
```

}

Comment: NSJSONSerialization never creates a NSData object. So, I'm wondering where you did get that NSData object. Anyway, if your html is embedded in JSON it is very likely already represented as a NSString.

Comment: please paste you code. that will help in finding the issue. i think you are requesting html data from back end.

Comment: i added my code check it and help me

Answer (score 2):

Try initWithData:encoding: method of NSString to create a string with your data.

Example:

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:someData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Hope it helps. Happy coding :)

Comment: no its not working.. json single data comes as html rest receives as normal string

Comment: follow this link it might help you, http://behindtechlines.com/2012/05/display-html-strings-plaintext-ios/

Answer (score 0):

Convert a NSString with HTML into a plain text string using NSXMLParser

```
NSString *urlString = @"www.myurl.com";
NSString *agentString = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_5_6; en-us) AppleWebKit/525.27.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.2.1 Safari/525.27.1";
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:
[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setValue:agentString forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
NSData *data = [ NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse: nil error: nil ];
NSString *returnData = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [data bytes] length:[data length] encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(returnData);
```

go to this [web](https://gist.github.com/drewmccormack/3840090)  or [this](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/41808-html-in-nsdata-converted-to-nsstring.html)